# Cannot get CORS to work in CouchDB 2.0

Tags: cors, couchdb

I have a CouchDB server running on my windows machine (localhost:5984).  I have enabled CORS in the webgui, and checked the local.ini file, those changes are good.

However, from another machine on my LAN, I cannot access :5984 nor :5986.

I have no idea what to do.  I am trying to get it such that a browser can GET and POST data from the DB on the host machine.

```
[cors]
origins = *
credentials = true
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token
```

...

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true
```

I have also tried "credentials = false" to no avail

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry I just figured it out... had to change the bind address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Comment: There is no need to keep this question opened. You should either remove your question (since the real problem was not related to the title) or define your answer as the good one.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for a solution:  make sure you changed bind address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 that was my issue.